# How to crop a word

Tags: bash, awk

I have this list of inputs :

```html
imalex
thislara
heiscarl
```

how to get :

```html
alex
lara
carl
```

Comment: how do you define "crop"? currently the only possible solution is `echo "alex"`

Comment: This is a ridiculously ill-considered question since `echo "alex\nlara\ncarl"` and a 100 or so other goofy "solutions" would produce the expected output. Despite how obvious it might be in your head, you've got to put a tiny bit of effort into explaining what the transformation is based on for us to have the same information.

Answer (score 4):

## grep

Use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to take the last four chars:

```
grep -o '.\{4\}$' file
```

The `-o` option makes sure only matched parts are printed.

## sed

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) we can achieve a similar result:

```
sed 's/.*\(.\{4\}\)$/\1/' a
```

Here we capture the last four digits and replace each line with those last four digits. They are captured in a group `\( \)` and inserted `\1`.

## read & tail

We can also grab the last five chars (including the newline) of each line using [tail](/questions/tagged/tail) and a `-c` option. We do that for each line using [read](/questions/tagged/read).

```
while read line; do 
    tail -c 5 <<< $line
done < file
```

Comment: this can be the solution, but the OP did not get information enough to know it. It might be best to wait for him to update with details, otherwise you can post an answer to his question and get no feedback to [your effort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31071747/1983854).

Comment: True, I may have been a bit too hasty. It's either the last four chars he wants or a drop of `iam`, `heis` and `sheis`. But you're right, it's unclear what the OP is asking, I assumed too quickly!

Answer (score 1):

2 answers using substring arithmetic

bash:

```
while read word; do
    echo "${word:${#word}-4}"
done <<<"$list"
```

awk

```
echo "$list" | awk '{print substr($NF, length($NF)-4+1)}'
```

Comment: I like the answer with the bash substitution, really clever!